# Jetty running as Windows service doesn't clean up temp file after shutdown

Tags: java, windows, service, jetty

I'm running Jetty 9.4.11.v20180605 as a Windows service with procrun. When I start this service Jetty extract the war into the temp folder. But when I shutdown the service Jetty doesn't delete these files on it's own.

To prevent the starting behaviour I changed the start.ini and set the jetty.deploy.extractWars to false. And it does what it should do but when I call the webapp I'm getting an HTTP ERROR 503 (Service Unavailable).

The second I've tried was to configure the WebAppContext in an xml file like this:

```
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
   <Set name="persistTempDirectory">false</Set>
</Configure>
```

As described [here](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-web-xml-config.html), I wrote it in a file named jetty-web.xml, put it into the WEB-INF folder of my webapp and it works but when I call the webapp in the browser it just show me the folder structure of my webapp. The same happens when I put the line below into the jetty-web-cdi2.xml for server configuration instead.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/9b7afd8a0341f4712031abd322ab8669f07f5c5b/jetty-documentation/src/main/asciidoc/administration/startup/startup-unix-service.adoc):

> The /opt/jetty/temp directory is created as a durable place for Jetty to use for temp and working directories. Many Unix systems will periodically clean out the /tmp directory, this behavior is undesired in a Servlet container and has been known to cause problems. This durable directory at /opt/jetty/temp solves for that behavior.

There seem to be a lot of unit tests for jetty that include temp files, and some specifically for checking if temp files are deleted.

https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/9706d70484863a014d3604e5e7cb4af40aa4cb1e/jetty-servlet/src/test/java/org/eclipse/jetty/servlet/MultiPartServletTest.java#L135

Files can have the property to be deleted on exit

https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/9706d70484863a014d3604e5e7cb4af40aa4cb1e/jetty-start/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/start/StartArgs.java#L792

So to summarize, it seems as if Jetty needs long living temp files, and does it's best to clean them up after they are no longer needed.

Comment: Does Windows delete files after a couple of days in EVERY folder named "temp"? Cause Jetty use it's own temp folder.

Comment: @TheFloorIsJava I modified my answer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe jetty want to do so but in fact it doesn't in my case. A customer of mine restarts the server where the webapp runs on every night so jettys temp folder become quite large without any clearance. So I have to find a workaround for this and I have:

I use the Windows temp folder to let jetty unpack the war. You can get this user based directory by typing %TMP% into the command line.
This folder won't be cleared automatically by standard settings in Windows. But you can manually clear it by using the disk cleanup tool in Windows. In Windows 10 you can also enable the automatically cleanup of the temp folder: "Windows Settings" -> "System" -> "Storage" -> turn on "Storage sense".
If you clear the temp folder by the disk cleanup tool, the current used folder and properties file of jetty won't be touched, so the webapp is still working after the cleanup.